# Simplify R code for detection and replacement of value names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large dataset.
The ID coloumn contains long and complicated names, and I want to replace these value names with more simple names.
They all have a continuous number included in their names, so I want to replace the long value name, with this simple number.
But since I have a lot of value names to replace, I get a long piece of code when writing a line for each value.
I'm looking for a way to reduce this code with a loop, or even better: In a tidy way, so that I don't have to write all these lines, where the only different thing is the continuous number

Here is some Dummy data and a short version of my pipeline replacing value names:

```
library(tidyverse)
ID <- c('number04', 'number05', 'number06', 'number07', 'number08', 'number09', 'number10')
df <- tibble(ID)

df <- df |>
 mutate(ID = if_else(str_detect(ID, pattern = "04"), "04", ID) |>
 mutate(ID = if_else(str_detect(ID, pattern = "05"), "05", ID) |>
 mutate(ID = if_else(str_detect(ID, pattern = "06"), "06", ID) |>
 mutate(ID = if_else(str_detect(ID, pattern = "07"), "07", ID) |>
 mutate(ID = if_else(str_detect(ID, pattern = "08"), "08", ID) |>
 mutate(ID = if_else(str_detect(ID, pattern = "09"), "09", ID) |>
 mutate(ID = if_else(str_detect(ID, pattern = "10"), "10", ID)
```

Comment: you can do: `readr::parse_number(df$ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `sub()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
 
df |>
  mutate(ID = sub("^number", "", ID))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 1
#>   ID   
#>   <chr>
#> 1 04   
#> 2 05   
#> 3 06   
#> 4 07   
#> 5 08   
#> 6 09   
#> 7 10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Data from OP

```r
ID <- c('number04', 'number05', 'number06', 'number07', 'number08', 'number09', 'number10')
df <- tibble(ID)
```